# How to reuse gulp tasks for multiple nodejs projects

Tags: node.js, gulp, node-modules

I am trying to reuse my `gulp` tasks in 2 different projects.  I extract my `gulp` tasks into a parent directory and am trying to require them in.  Here is my directory structure.

```
parent/
    gulp-tasks/
      default.js
    project1/
        node_modules/
        gulpfile.js
        js/
    project2/
        node_modules/
        gulpfile.js
        js/
```

This is all that I have in my `gulpfile.js` in each project

```js
var requireDir = require('require-dir');
requireDir('../gulptasks');
```

Here is what my `default.js` looks like:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp');

gulp.task('default', function() {
    //run code here
})
```

When I try to run `gulp default`, I get that `gulp` is not defined.  I know that there are no `node_modules` in the parent directory, but is there any way to point to the `node_modules` in each of the child projects?  I am not particularly wanting an answer about gulp but how to structure my projects to make my code reusable?

Comment: Did you install `gulp` globally?

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you need to structure that way? Can you break them down into repos? That way you can install each of them as dependencies.
2. You can have the package.json within the `parent` root. Then you would have access to the shared `node_modules` folders.

Comment: My core stuff is still in flux and it seems like a nightmare to have a build process where you have to wait for the core stuff to get pushed to the registry and then to pull it down to build the child project.

Comment: You can install git repos directly. `npm install git+ssh://<repo> --save`